# Ruby chain two 'group_by' methods

Tags: ruby

I have an array of objects that looks like this:

```
[
  {day: 'Monday', class: 1, name: 'X'},
  {day: 'Monday', class: 2, name: 'Y'},
  {day: 'Tuesday', class: 1, name: 'Z'},
  {day: 'Monday', class: 1, name: 'T'}
]
```

I want to group them by days, and then by classes i.e.

```
groupedArray['Monday'] => {'1' => [{name: 'X'}, {name: 'T'}], '2' => [{name: 'Y'}]}
```

I've seen there is a

```
group_by { |a| [a.day, a.class]}
```

But this creates a hash with a [day, class] key.

Is there a way I can achieve this, without having to group them first by day, and then iterate through each day, and group them by class, then pushing them into a new hash?

Comment: Are you sure you don't want `groupedArray['Monday'] => {'1' => [{name: 'X'}, {name: 'T'}], '2' => [{name: 'Y'}]}`? I expect that accounts for the downvotes.

Comment: Yes, that's what I want. Didn't notice the wrong brackets, sorry

Comment: Just wanted to know if there's a shorter way to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
arr = [
  {day: 'Monday',  class: 1, name: 'X'},
  {day: 'Monday',  class: 2, name: 'Y'},
  {day: 'Tuesday', class: 1, name: 'Z'},
  {day: 'Monday',  class: 1, name: 'T'}
]
```

One way of obtaining the desired hash is to use the form of [Hash#update](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-update) (aka merge!) that employs a block to determine the values of keys that are present in both hashes being merged. Here that is done twice, first when values of `:day` are the same, then for each such occurrence, when the values of `:class` are the same (for a given value of `:day`).

```
arr.each_with_object({}) { |g,h|
  h.update(g[:day]=>{ g[:class].to_s=>[{name: g[:name] }] }) { |_,h1,h2|
    h1.update(h2) { |_,p,q| p+q } } }
  #=> {"Monday" =>{"1"=>[{:name=>"X"}, {:name=>"T"}], "2"=>[{:name=>"Y"}]},
  #    "Tuesday"=>{"1"=>[{:name=>"Z"}]}}
```

The steps are as follows.

```
enum = arr.each_with_object({})
  #=> #<Enumerator: [{:day=>"Monday",  :class=>1, :name=>"X"},
  #                  {:day=>"Monday",  :class=>2, :name=>"Y"},
  #                  {:day=>"Tuesday", :class=>1, :name=>"Z"},
  #                  {:day=>"Monday",  :class=>1, :name=>"T"}]:each_with_object({})>
```

We can see the values that will be generated by this enumerator by converting it to an array:

```
enum.to_a
  #=> [[{:day=>"Monday",  :class=>1, :name=>"X"}, {}],
  #    [{:day=>"Monday",  :class=>2, :name=>"Y"}, {}],
  #    [{:day=>"Tuesday", :class=>1, :name=>"Z"}, {}],
  #    [{:day=>"Monday",  :class=>1, :name=>"T"}, {}]]
```

The empty hash in each array is the hash being built and returned. It is initially empty, but will be partially formed as each element of `enum` is processed.

The first element of `enum` is passed to the block (by [Enumerator#each](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerator.html#method-i-each)) and the block variables are assigned using *parallel assignment* (somtimes called *multiple assignment*):

```
g,h = enum.next
  #=> [{:day=>"Monday", :class=>1, :name=>"X"}, {}] 
g #=> {:day=>"Monday", :class=>1, :name=>"X"} 
h #=> {}
```

We now perform the block calculation:

```
h.update(g[:day]=>{ g[:class].to_s=>[{name: g[:name] }] })
  #=> {}.update("Monday"=>{ "1"=>[{name: "X"}] })
  #=> {"Monday"=>{"1"=>[{:name=>"X"}]}}
```

This operation returns the updated value of `h`, the hash being constructed.

Note that `update`'s argument

```
"Monday"=>{ "1"=>[{name: "X"}] }
```

is shorthand for

```
{ "Monday"=>{ "1"=>[{name: "X"}] } }
```

Because the key `"Monday"` was not present in both hashes being merged (`h` had no keys), the block

```
{ |_,h1,h2| h1.update(h2) { |_,p,q| p+q } } }
```

was not used to determine the value of `"Monday"`.

Now the next value of `enum` is passed to the block and the block variables are assigned:

```
g,h = enum.next
  #=> [{:day=>"Monday", :class=>2, :name=>"Y"},
  #    {"Monday"=>{"1"=>[{:name=>"X"}]}}] 
g #=> {:day=>"Monday", :class=>2, :name=>"Y"} 
h #=> {"Monday"=>{"1"=>[{:name=>"X"}]}}
```

Note that `h` was updated. We now perform the block calculation:

```
h.update(g[:day]=>{ g[:class].to_s=>[{name: g[:name] }] })
  # {"Monday"=>{"1"=>[{:name=>"X"}]}}.update("Monday"=>{ "2"=>[{name: "Y"}] })
```

Both hashes being merged share the key "Monday". We therefore must use the block to determine the merged value of "Monday":

```
{ |k,h1,h2| h1.update(h2) { |m,p,q| p+q } } }
  #=> {"1"=>[{:name=>"X"}]}.update("2"=>[{name: "Y"}])
  #=> {"1"=>[{:name=>"X"}], "2"=>[{:name=>"Y"}]}
```

See the doc for `update` for an explanation of the block variables `k`, `h1` and `h2` for the outer `update` and `m`, `p` and `q` for the inner `update`. `k` and `m` are the values of the common key. As they are not used in the block calculations, I have replaced them with underscores, which is common practice.

So now:

```
h #=> { "Monday" => { "1"=>[{ :name=>"X" }], "2"=>[{ :name=>"Y"}] } }
```

Prior to this operation the hash `h["Monday]` did not yet have a key `2`, so the second `update` did not require use of the block

```
{ |_,p,q| p+q }
```

This block is used, however, when the last element of `enum` is merged into `h`, since the values of both `:day` and `:class` are the same for the two hashes being merged.

The remaining calculations are similar.

Comment: An outstanding answer, but most of your answers are.